# Handle click from custom view controller using swift in ios

Tags: ios, swift

[storyboard snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIzoJ.png)[crash report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTcmd.png) I am new in iOS development, I have a View Controller in main storyboard except main view Controller. In custom view controller I have put a button and when I click the button from custom view controller layout, app crashes.
How to handle click events or any kind of web view or events? Is there anything in iOS like manifest in android for declaring new view controller?

I want to link with 'Build your sandae' button which is written in CustomWig view controller
Kindly reply to the post.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the crash along with the error message. 

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/102811 - check this link for more clarification

Comment: "Unrecognized selector sent to instance" is a well known error. Did you look for it? Might be a method that you linked between a UIButton tap and the code, but which method has been renamed afterwards...

Comment: This is a pretty common error, have you tried googling `unrecognized selector sent to instance`?

Comment: I have googled it several times but I can't understand the reason. How to handle clicks or any event from custom view controller. I will be thankful if anyone kindly reply me back as soon as possible.

Comment: What is `CustomWig`? You need to show code. Does it have a method named `btnBuild`? How did you link the action to the method? In Storyboard? By code with `addTarget`...

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue with taken action handler from your current custom screen to another main screen.

> In main screen you need to implement that handler and in custom view
> you need to declare and call that button action handler method.

in your CustomScreen add callBack like this

**var actionHandler: (() -> Void)?**

than call this callback when click on button

**self.actionHandler?()**

now go to their main screen where your customScreen and initialize it and put this code for handling button action

```
 vc.actionHandler = { 
    //do your code here
 }
```

Here "vc" is your custom screen instance.

Comment: can you kindly elaborate the topic clearly?

Comment: @Abhi, Checked my updated solution with example, I hope it will help you.